# Missing bullets when itemize is justified

Tags: beamer, itemize, presentations, bullets

Good day,

Why bullets disappear when an itemize list is justified?

```
\RequirePackage{flashmovie}
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
      \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}
    }
  \vskip0pt%
}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Presentacion.bib}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Tabla de contenidos}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}
\begin{document}
\justify
\begin{frame}{Definici\'on de Qu\'imica}
\begin{itemize} \justify
  \item ?`Porqu\'e el cielo es azul?
  \item ?`Porqu\'e el agua puede estar en estado s\'olido, l\'iquido o     gaseoso?
  \item ?`Porqu\'e la comida cambia de color?
  \item ?`Porqu\'e identificamos personas u objetos por su olor?
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `\justifying` instead of `\justify`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Definici\'on de Qu\'imica}
\begin{itemize} 
    \justifying
  \item ?`Porqu\'e el cielo es azul?
  \item \lipsum[2]
  \item ?`Porqu\'e la comida cambia de color?
  \item ?`Porqu\'e identificamos personas u objetos por su olor?
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cloud you consider making clear what the actual problem was so the reader does not have to reverse-engineer it from the code samples. A short sentence would suffice.

Comment: @Christoph90 Done :)